# Line length marker in nano

Tags: nano

How can I highlight a given column using nano?

I'm using a fairly large terminal but I would like a mark to know if my code exceeds the limit of let's say 80 characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command-line options:

```
nano -J 80 file
nano --guidestripe 80 file
```

Or add this to `~/.nanorc`:

```
set guidestripe 80
```

That information is to be found in [the manual](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html) under section 3. Notice that feature is absent for versions of `nano` [older than 4.0](https://www.nano-editor.org/news.php).

Comment: This isn't working for me. The version shown at the top of the window is `UW PICO 5.09`.

Comment: So nano on macOS is actually Pico?

Comment: I've just confirmed that runninig `$ nano <new file name>` on macOS (12.3.1) Terminal gives the above version number. not sure what to make of it.

Comment: [GNU nano was designed to be a free replacement for the Pico text editor](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/faq.html#1.1). As such, I guess Macos tries to make things easier by having a Nano alias or symlink that invokes Pico. Definetely, were it Nano, the version wouldn't say PICO 5.09.

Comment: How would one set multiple guidestripes?